# Android : Able to view jar source in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, build.gradle

I've included jar file in my application. I can able to see jar sources in android studio. How to avoid this?

I've made changes in build.gradle file in jar project

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to avoid seeing the sources? You can see sources in Android studio without them being bundled in your release.

Comment: buildType will take affect after you build your app, not before.

Comment: S after the above steps i'm building the project and i'm using the jar in my application